# how to iterate on selected rows with datables + select extension

Tags: datatables

I use the select extension an d try to 'alert' with the id of the selected rows.

the following code fails:

```
let sels = jqTable.api().rows({ selected: true });
let st = '';
sels.each(function (value, index) {
    st += ',' + sels.row(value).id();
});
alert(st);
```

The function is called once independently of selected rows:

- 0 row: `value = [], index = 0`
- >=1 : `value = [0, 2], index = 0`

The following code succeeds:

```
let sels = jqTable.api().rows({ selected: true });
let st = '';
for (let i = 0; i < sels.count(); i++) {
    st += ',' + sels.row(sels[0][i]).id();
}
alert(st);
```

what do I missunderstand with [each()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/each()) :

> Iterate over the contents of the API result set.

I notice that the following code runs:

```
sels.data().each(function (value, index) {
    st += ',' + value.IdFile;
});
```

But using it cancels the advantage of `rowId : 'IdFile'` in the datatable configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`each()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/each()) is used when the dataset returns an array of results within the API objects - in the case of [`rows()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows()) this isn't the case - it returns a single result, which happen to be an array containing the rowIDs of the selected rows.

Your first code block fails as there's only one iteration (the results are a single array).

Your second block works, because you're iterating over that single array (`sels[0]`).

And your third also works, as the [`rows().data()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows().data()) does generate an array containing the data of all the selected rows.

This [example](http://live.datatables.net/foxoqusi/1/edit) will hopefully help!